# Does the Rec Room Studio Performance Explorer account for static batching?

Tags: unity, performance

The Performance Explorer in Rec Room studio appears to be doing the naive calculation for draw calls where it just adds up unique materials on unique meshes.

[image]

In the above image, all of the meshes with the highest number of draw calls are marked as static.

I migrated the scene containing those objects to a fresh unity project without Rec Room studio and launched the frame debugger. The image below shows the number of draw calls (353) used to render the entire scene. As you can see, static batching is pulling some serious weight, which we were relying on in authoring these assets- they were always meant to be static.

[image]

Are the number of draw calls reported in the Rec Room Studio Performance Explorer considering static batching at all? Is this only meant to show worst case scenario for draw calls? Or is this indicating that Rec Room does not support static batching?

Comment: Questions about possible bugs in third-party assets rarely get answered. You're best off contacting the company that makes Rec Room Studio.

Comment: @Kevin I've cross posted it to their discord server and they'll answer it here once they reply, that way everyone can have access to the information.